# How to set HTTP proxy and proxy authentication credentials in wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, authorization, proxy

I have set up wifi, I installed HTTP proxy and configured it, but where I put the proxy authentication credentials?

Comment: Use [Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony&hl=en), it sets up proxy for the whole system (with authentication), no root is required.

Comment: @YukioFukuzawa you should add that comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://android-proxy.blogspot.com/), you need an external app **and** you need to root the phone.

Some other solutions shared in a [Google Code issue thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273).

**Update**:

Using [Gesture Search](http://www.appbrain.com/app/gesture-search/com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch), I entered "proxy" and got to the Proxy settings on my Droid. Don't know how to get there otherwise, and don't know if it actually works, but there you go. (Someone else mentioned it in that Google thread.)

Answer (score 3):

To modify the proxy settings in **Android 4** and **Samsung Galaxy** you should do this:

Go to **Settings** / **Wifi**. Long-click on your network and select **Modify network**. Scroll down to **Show advanced options** which should show you the proxy options.

Comment: The question was about using proxy authentication.  The proxy settings in Android don't allow entering authentication details.

Answer (score 2):

My Samsung Galaxy S II has proxy settings enabled under

Settings > Wireless & Network > Wifi settings > Advanced

I can set a proxy address and a port number.

The proxy I'm sitting behind requires authentication tho and I'm having trouble finding these settings.

Comment: Note that you need to press Menu to see the Advanced option, it's not one options on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Proxy Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/http-proxy-settings/org.credil.proxysettings), a free app that reveals the Proxy settings button available in most stock ROMs.

Comment: The question was about using proxy authentication.  The proxy settings in Android don't allow entering authentication details.

Answer (score 0):

Right under where you put your proxy settings (Settings - > Wifi - > Long click your network -> Manage settings -> Advanced -> Proxy -> manual) you can put your username and password.
[image: Android Proxy Settings]

Keep in mind that some apps (e,g: chrome) do not recognize those settings and will ask you for credentials in the first time (as of oct 18)

This also imply you can use authenticated proxy in .pac file while using chrome.

Comment: Which version of Android was this screenshot taken? I'm running Android 9 and everything from "Authenticate server" on down is missing from my manual proxy settings.

Comment: Android 7 (on Galaxy 6), this is the latest I own.