# NTLM authorization proxy on Android

Tags: authorization, proxy, ntlm

Is it possible to run NTLM authorization proxy on Android? It is written in Python, and should provide proxy compatibility.

See also this question:

[How to set HTTP proxy and proxy authentication credentials in wifi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/how-to-set-http-proxy-and-proxy-authentication-credentials-in-wifi)

Comment: This is an awfully open-ended question. This isn't a discussion forum. How will you choose the one, best answer? Please see the FAQ and rephrase this into a question that could have a single correct answer.

Comment: I've made the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer to your question exactly, but it solves the main issue. I have coded a solution for this, you can download the apk on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1083284. It uses a cntlm binary to process the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a non-root NTLM proxy here: http://humanos.uci.cu/2015/03/humancode-llega-la-version-3-9-de-ucintlm/ The site is in spanish but the app works for english too. I'm the developer of this app.

Comment: I made it to upload it to google play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uci.ucintlm