# Use wifi in HTC Dream behind a proxy

Tags: wi-fi, htc-dream, 1.5-cupcake, proxy

I wish to use wifi network in my university but the network resides behind a proxy server. So, how do I set my proxy settings (requires authentication) on my HTC Dream G1 (Android 1.5)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HTTP proxy and proxy authentication credentials in wifi?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/how-to-set-http-proxy-and-proxy-authentication-credentials-in-wifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings -> Wireless and Network -> WiFi Settings`, hit the Menu button, and choose Advanced.

However, it appears this doesn't support user authentication. I can't find a solution online, either :(.  The question I marked as a duplicate may be of some assistance, though your version of Android may be too old for any of this.

Comment: Will creating an APN and setting it up help? I know that APN is used for GPRS but I am not sure it is used for wifi too or not

Comment: You could have a computer rebroadcast the university's WiFi network if you have the appropriate OS/hardware, allowing the computer to manage the proxy settings and the phone to connect blithely through the computer.  [Example instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-rebroadcast-WIFI-as-your-own-network-FROM-/).

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. It detects the wifi network but does not connect to it. My internet access on my laptop is through a LAN connection with static IP address, maybe thats creating problems. Maybe I can do something similar on Ubuntu as it isnt working on Windows 7.

Comment: it might be possible to set auth info with the server url, i.e. `user:pass@proxy.server.tld`. I never tried it myself (not having a proxy to try with), but heard people reporting success this way.