# Setup proxy authentication in Android 4.1.2

Tags: proxy

I tried to setup my Wifi proxy via Setting but can't find any authentication I can put anywhere.

Looking from this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/how-to-set-http-proxy-and-proxy-authentication-credentials-in-wifi) and another thread, looks like I need to root my phone. Can I setup my proxy with authentication without rooting my phone?

Comment: Finally got one app that works like charm! http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2276765

Comment: why not add an answer for this, with some details from the XDA link, and accept it as the official answer. You'll earn rep and you'll be helping others with this same issue! Glad you found a solution!